# decoupling the URLConfs(Python/Django): current URL does not match any URL pattern after ERROR

Tags: python, django

I have just started teaching myself python/django and have been following the django tutorials. I have got stuck at the decoupling of URLConfs. I have copied the code to respective files from the tutorial but I am getting this error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^polls/ ^/$
    ^polls/ ^/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$
    ^polls/ ^/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$
    ^polls/ ^/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$
    ^admin/
The current URL, polls/, didn't match any of these.
```

I have got urls.py in both mysite and polls folder as asked by the tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/)

Comment: Try removing the leading slashes from the regex patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** remove the first `/` in the URL configs on `polls.urls`.

**Long explanation:**
The problem here, as Julian mentioned in the comments is that you have an extra slash in the URL configs.

When you have the following in your root URL config:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
```

This essentially 'chops off' the `polls/` part of the URL string and passes the rest on to `polls.urls`. So if you try and get the URL `polls/13/results`, the `polls/` will be handled by `my site.urls` and the rest will be given to `polls.urls`.

Your `polls.urls` file seems to be requiring a preceding `/` on the string however, and because this has been removed already it doesn't exist. The caret `^` character means the beginning of the string so all of your configs at the moment *require* that they start with a `/` at the point that `polls.urls` receives them, they shouldn't do this otherwise you are expecting the following:

```
/polls//13/results
```

instead of:

```
/polls/13/results
```

I hope this answers everything!